# Video failed to upload to Microsoft Stream

Tags: office-365, office-web-apps, microsoft-teams

So we usually record our meetings through Teams and these get automatically uploaded to Stream. However yesterday the auto upload failed presenting this message:

[image: recording failed to upload to Stream]

I downloaded the video manually (through Teams). I was hoping to upload this video to our Stream manually, however everytime I try I receive the following error message:

**video.mp4 failed to upload. Changes to this Microsoft Stream tenant are temporarily disabled. Please try again later.
Failed: video.mp4**

Any ideas what this is to do with?

I have tried multiple times yesterday and today.
Also asked another team member to try and they receive the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so did some further digging and eventually decided to raise a ticket with Microsoft - so the data centre is currently doing a migration of Microsoft Stream data, and should be back up either tomorrow (Friday 1st Nov) or Monday 4th Nov apparently. If anyone else is having a similar issue with Stream this could be why (if your data centre is in the UK).

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Stream-Service-Updates/Scheduled-Maintenance-UK-Only-Microsoft-Stream-Data-Datacenter/m-p/897717